# How to pass Mojo function to Python in Python interop?

Tags: python, mojolang

The question is how to pass Mojo function to Python in Python interop?

For example,

```py
# This is main.mojo
from python.python import Python

def callback():
    return 5

def main():
  Python.add_to_path(".")
  let test_module = Python.import_module("lib")
  print(test_module.test_interop(callback))
```

```py
# This is lib.py
def test_interop(func):
    return func()
```

If I run this, it will show the following message:

```
$ main.mojo
main.mojo:9:33: error: invalid call to '__call__': argument #1 cannot be converted from 'fn() raises -> object' to 'PythonObject'
  print(test_module.test_interop(callback))
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
main.mojo:1:1: note: function declared here
from python.python import Python
^
mojo: error: failed to parse the provided Mojo
```

Comment: I ran your code and get the same error. It can be inferred that a function defined in `mojo` even with `def` is different from that it is in Python. In error message, you can see its type is `fn() raises -> object` and the functions for  Python in mojo is defined as `PythonObject`. The manual did not mention how do deal with this yet... But if you try a more simple way, it will work. Such as just call `print` in a python file. What if and how to use python to execute a mojo function(which is your `callback`) is still not clear. I will check if there is a corresponding issue in their github

Comment: I tried wrapping the function with `PythonObejct` but Mojo is unable to marshall it into Python value.

Comment: I've opened a issue [here](https://github.com/modularml/mojo/issues/621), hoping the contributors to response

Comment: The community has responded, and the answer is ”it is not supported yet“

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this isn't a feature supported in Mojo yet but it is something planned for sometime in the future.